# How do I connect Starcraft 2 and Facebook?

Tags: starcraft-2, facebook

I've been reading that Starcraft 2 has facebook integration. But how do I actually connect my accounts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you log onto battle.net, go to your "Home" page by clicking the little house button.

As you can see there, is a button which says "Import Friends" next to the Facebook icon. Select this, and enter in your Facebook credentials.

If the broadcast has expired, select your friends:

[image]

Click "add friends":

[image]

Select "add Facebook Friends."

Comment: My recent broadcasts window is empty.

Answer (score 5):

As of January 2013, Facebook integration has been removed by Blizzard because Facebook

> [...] changed their API usage policy and decided to prevent third-party
>   games like StarCraft II from utilizing their network to make social
>   connections.

http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/7592202481

Answer (score 2):

Click the friends list button at the lower right hand of the task bar (left of the clock/mic)

there will be a button for 'add friend'

Click that and you will see a button for facebook.